# Google unofficial api - Error retrieving information from server. [RH-01]

Tags: python, api, google-api, open-source

i'm using this [Google Play Unofficial Python API](https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api)

After I installed google's protobuf and followed all the instructions giving, I called the api like so:

```
python categories.py
```

and got nothing. ( I mean NOTHING)

I digged into the code a little bit and I found how to print the error, this is it: `Error retrieving information from server. [RH-01]`

I want to add that I printed some more logs that I cant put up here but login seems ok, Its just the calls to the api that cause this error.

Have anyone encountered this problem before? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after a little bit of digging iv'e found that you need to use GSF in the ANDROID_ID instead of the actual android id.

Good luck!